# Stored drawable become changed in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drawable

ImageView background chanded to last one size while onResume

```
lateinit var bgImage: NinePatchDrawable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_easy)

        bgImage = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tm_bg_special) as NinePatchDrawable

        iv1.background = bgImage
        iv2.background = bgImage
        iv3.background = bgImage
        iv4.background = bgImage

        // It works fine if I use drawable directly to each imageView
        iv1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tm_bg_special) as NinePatchDrawable
        iv2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tm_bg_special) as NinePatchDrawable
        iv3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tm_bg_special) as NinePatchDrawable
        iv4.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tm_bg_special) as NinePatchDrawable
    }
```

It works fine if I use drawable directly to each imageView but I want to store the Drawable because it is creadted in runtime in orginal situation and need set to large number of imageView

What happen visually...
[image]

Referance xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv4"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think while the system sets the bgImage to views it will resize the bgImage itself. That means the bgImage will be using the size of the view that it is last assigned to.

You can try this to see if all the image becomes large:

```
    iv4.background = bgImage
    iv3.background = bgImage
    iv2.background = bgImage
    iv1.background = bgImage
```

If that’s the case, what you can do is to create four NinePatchDrawable and reuse them.